# How to unite separate lists of json objects into one array of objects?

Tags: json, angular, mapping

I am getting data from database in this form.

there is array of object and each object looks like this.

```
  },
  {
    "vehicleId": 2287,
    "plateNumber": "GGS-733",
    "vehicleTypeId": 1,
    "driverId": null,
    "garageId": 1,
    "statusId": 0,
    "vehicleModelId": 18,
    "additionalInfo": null,
    "techInspectDate": "00:00:00",
    "person": null
  },
  {
```

I am also getting the lists of objects included in here separately. (garageId, statusId, vehicletypeId). Each of them have different values(for example vehicleType). I want to map them correctly to new object that Instead of Ids will have the values of these objects.

I want to have an end result an object that will look like this.

```
  },
  {
    "vehicleId": 2287,
    "plateNumber": "GGS-733",
    --> "vehicleType": "SUV",
    --> "driver": "John Smith",
    --> "garage": "Boston",
    --> "statusId": "available",
    "vehicleModelId": 18,
    "additionalInfo": null,
    "techInspectDate": "00:00:00",
    "person": null
  },
  {
```

There are several problems that I'm facing. I need to wait for all the lists to be fetched fully first, until I try to map everything to new object. I need to make the order of asynchronous events is correct. And I can't leave the lists in separate objects and access it when needed. My end result needs to be one object, like specified before and I need to give it to a function, which later will display its values on front-end.

Currently I'm getting the list of garages and other objects like this.

```
  public getGarages(): Observable<any[]> {
    const url = `${this.serviceUrl}lists/garages`;
    return this.http.get<any[]>(url);
  }
```

Earlier database was giving me whole tree. Meaning that vehicles included the whole garage object instead of just garageid. So I had getVehicles function do the mapping for each of its object, taking children values and copying it into new value in the object. but now I have only the Id.

```
getVehicles(): Observable<Vehicle[]> {
     const url = `${this.serviceUrl}`;
     return this.http.get<Vehicle[]>(url).pipe(
      tap(vehiclesArray => vehiclesArray.forEach(element => {

      //  element.garageName = element.garage.garageName;
      //  element.status = element.vehicleStatus.status;
      //  element.vtype = element.vehicleType.vehicleType;
      //  element.ownerName = element.owner.ownerName;
      //  element.vehicleModelName = element.vehicleModel.vehicleModelName;
      })));
  }
```

One of my thoughts is to make some kind of counter, checking if all subscribes have been finished, so that in the main vehicles function, I know I got all the data ready.

Another thought I got was to let one function call another until I get to the main vehicles function, but that might slow down the process, because the calls will happen in sequence and not at the same time.

**How do I achieve the end result?** 
**What is the efficient and correct approach?**

Comment: Both api calls aren't dependent as in for url params?

Comment: yes they have different urls. one is url/vehicles other is url/lists/garages

Comment: I actually solved the problem. I will write the answer once I finish up the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling the vehicles function last, I realized it's better to call it first and get the data and later edit the objects. I wrote functions that get the JSON list from html response. After I get the list I looped through the list and looped through my vehicles object and copied the value if the id's match.

This is  my getVehicles code

```
getVehicles() {
    this.fleetService.getVehicles()
    .subscribe(value => {
      this.vehicles = value;
      this.getGarages();
      this.getVehicleTypes();
      this.getVehicleModels();
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.vehicles);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    });
  }
```

in vehicles I call getGarages and other functions in subscribe, so that the data is ready for the functions to edit it.

all the functions look the same:

```
getGarages(): void {
    this.fleetService.getGarages().subscribe(result => {
      this.garages = result;
      this.vehicles.forEach(function (element) {
        this.garages.forEach(garage => {
          if (garage.garageId === element.garageId) {
            element.garageName = garage.garageName;
          }
        });
      }.bind(this));
    });
  }
```

the only problem I find in my solution is that I am looping through my vehicles object every time. Instead of looping once and adding all the values. If anybody has better ideas please share.